# How to display members of nested arrays on the screen by solving "Value of type '[Book]' has no member 'name'"?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to build a bible app. My approach is to use JSON Bible which I converted from XML. The reason is I couldn't find how to parse XML format in swiftui. This is my converted JSON file.

```
{
  "bible" : {
    "@translation" : "version",
    "book" : [ {
      "@name" : "Genesis",
      "chapter" : [ {
        "@name" : "1",
        "verse" : [ {
          "@name" : "1",
          "$" : "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth."
        }, {
          "@name" : "2",
          "$" : "Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters."
        }, ....
```

Also, I created delegates such as:

```
import Foundation

struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let bible: Bible
    
    static let example = Welcome(bible: Bible(translation: "version", book: [Book(name: "Genesis", chapter: [Chapter(name: "1", verse: [Verse(name: "1", empty: "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.")])])]))
}

struct Bible: Decodable {
    let translation: String
        let book: [Book]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case translation = "@translation"
            case book
        }
    //static let example2 = Bible(book: [Book(name: "Genesis", chapter: [Chapter])])
}

struct Book: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let chapter: [Chapter]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "@name"
        case chapter
    }
}

struct Chapter: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let verse: [Verse]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "@name"
        case verse
    }
}

struct Verse: Decodable {
    let name, empty: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "@name"
        case empty = "$"
    }
}
```

Here, I am trying to display it in my canvas, but I couldn't figure out how to implement the nested array members. Below is my dummy approach and it always shows me errors.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Scripture1: View {
    
    var welcome: Welcome
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            Text(welcome.bible.translation)
            Text(welcome.bible.book.name) // Here is the error that says "Value of type '[Book]' has no member 'name'"
            
                
        }
        
    }
}

struct Scripture1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Scripture1(welcome: Welcome.example)
    }
}
```

Also, please lead me if there is a better approach to display the scripture on the canvas without using JSON file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `book: [Book]`(consider renaming to `books`) is an array, which means you need `ForEach` to display all of items in your view. Same goes to `chapter` and `verse`:

```
struct Scripture1: View {
    
    var welcome: Welcome
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            Text(welcome.bible.translation)
            
            ForEachIndexed(welcome.bible.book) { i, book in
                Text(book.name)
                ForEachIndexed(book.chapter) { i, chapter in
                    Text(chapter.name)
                    ForEachIndexed(chapter.verse) { i, verse in
                        Text(verse.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ForEachIndexed<Data: RandomAccessCollection, Content: View, ID: Hashable>: View {
    let data: [EnumeratedSequence<Data>.Element]
    let content: (Int, Data.Element) -> Content
    let id: KeyPath<EnumeratedSequence<Data>.Element, ID>
    
    init(
        _ data: Data,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, Data.Element) -> Content,
        id: KeyPath<EnumeratedSequence<Data>.Element, ID> = \.element.id
    ) where Data.Element: Identifiable, ID == Data.Element.ID {
        self.data = Array(data.enumerated())
        self.content = content
        self.id = id
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data, id: id) { element in
            content(element.offset, element.element)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you gonna need to update your list animatedly, `ForEachIndexed` won't gonna work as you expect: you gonna need add some unique identifiers to all of your objects so `ForEach` can distinguish one from the other by confirming to `Identifiable` and replace `ForEachIndexed` with plain `ForEach`

Comment: Thanks, @Philip. It works and book: [Book] is the correct one. Thank you for helping me out. Also, is there a way that I could combine to print chapter and verse inside ForEach?

Comment: @Lian these are arrays too, so you need to add two more nested `ForEach`; I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: There is no way I can figure it out by myself. Thanks a lot. It is working now. God bless you, Philip.