# List is not showing data from API in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to get data from API and want to show that in List.

```
  List {
                ForEach(0 ..< (declarationViewModel.items?.count)!) { index in

                    HStack {
......
```

but as its taking some time to fetch data from API, initially data is 0 hence can not able to show data in list as it's not reloading after getting data.

```
public class DeclarationViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var items: [Item]?
    @Published var title: String?

    init() {
        self.items = [Item]()
        self.title = ""
    }

    init(items: [Item]?, title: String) {
        self.items = items
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Error log

```
forEach<Range<Int>, Int, HStack<TupleView<(HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _FrameLayout>, Text, Spacer)>>, Spacer, _ConditionalContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _FrameLayout>, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _FrameLayout>>, _ConditionalContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _FrameLayout>, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _FrameLayout>>)>>> count (14) != its initial count (0). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!
```

Comment: can you show us how you declare, or pass in `declarationViewModel` in the view with your List. Also do you, for example have a `onAppear{...}` where you fetch the data?

Comment: Hello, did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your console, you'll see following warning:

> ForEach<Range, Int, ModifiedContent<Text, AddGestureModifier<_EndedGesture>>> count (2) != its initial count (1). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Newer use `0..<shoppingList.count` inside `ForEach` or `List`. At least use `declarationViewModel.items.indices` instead.

Make `items` non optional by specifying a default value of an empty array instead of initializing it in the `init`. You can do same with `title`:

```
@Published var items: [Item] = []
@Published var title = ""
```

But perfectly instead of using `indices` you need to confirm your `Item` to `Identifiable` and make sure each item has a unique `id`, so your animations will work good and SwiftUI reuse cells to increase performance. You can use `UUID`:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}
```

Then in `ForEach` you get item instead of index:

```
ForEach(declarationViewModel.items) { item in
```

If you also need index in `ForEach`, check out my `ForEachIndexed` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900976/how-to-display-members-of-nested-arrays-on-the-screen-by-solving-value-of-type/68901021#68901021)

Comment: Thank you for answer but can i use , id:\.self to make sure each item has unique id?... I have updated my issue log also

Comment: @Rahul you can go with `indices`, check out first part of my answer to fix your issue(before "But perfectly"). But if you have an array and then lets say insert a new item at first index, your second item(which was originally the first) will change its id, and so will all other items do, so SwiftUI will have to redraw all of them instead of inserting just one

Comment: @Rahul In general, `id: \.self` isn't a great idea (not to mean you should never use it). In the future your code or data may change for whatever `Item` is, you may have duplicates. There's even the risk of user input causing identical items, depending what this is for. In this case, as Philip said in his answer, this could cause numerous problems. Just conform `Item` to `Identifiable` and provide it some unique ID. I would only really use `id: \.self` when I **know** the data is unique - it's not based on user input. This could be an array of pre-defined color names, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something simple like this:

EDIT: and if your items are Identifiable, then remove the "id:.\self",
nothing to it.

```
List {
    if let items = declarationViewModel.items {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            ....
        }
    }
}
```